# D3.js animating update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with something like this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skyeleven/1asfwyz5/1/)

I'm loading data with `jQuery` and running the whole update function with it. What I want to do is have all the circles run closer to the main one before the update is triggered. Would I be able to do something like that? I've tried rewriting the `tick` function to do same as it does now, only to use `d.x-50`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you better describe what you want? It's not very clear, specially because you have set `linkDistance` explicitly in the code.

Comment: That's right, I'd like to reduce the `linkDistance` just before I trigger the update function. So maybe override it, or maybe change x/y directly for each node and link? The idea is they get closer to the main node and update. Like a "pulse" effect, does that help any?

Comment: Ok, that's better!

Comment: Perfect. I could add the `jQuery` as well, but all it does is ajax the data and trigger the update, so don't think that's helpful a lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want, but this is my solution: restart the force with a smaller `linkDistance`:

```
var inter = setInterval(function() {
    updateData();
    setTimeout(function() {
        force.linkDistance(20);
        force.start().alpha(0.01);
    }, 2000);
}, 5000);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = {

    nodes: [
   {"x": 250, "y": 250, "color": "green", "name":"TEST", "r":"28", "fixed":true},
    {"x": 120, "y": 150, "name":"forums.macrumors", "score": -12.2, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 140, "y": 150, "name":"delhidailynews", "score": -0.08, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 150, "name":"4-traders", "score": -0.055, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 300, "y": 150, "name":"phonearena", "score": 0.45, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 40, "y": 200, "name":"inga3.wordpress", "score": -0.27, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 70, "y": 200, "name":"kahinaweb.wordpress", "score": -0.28, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 100, "y": 200, "name":"bilqueessite.wordpress", "score": -0.3, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 130, "y": 200, "name":"beforeitsnews", "score": -0.72, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 380, "y": 200, "name":"yahoo", "score": -0.66, "icon": ""}    
    ],
   links: [
    {"source":  0, "target": 1, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 2, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 3, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 4, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 5, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 6, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 7, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 8, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 9, "distance": 180, "label": ""}
   

    
  ]
    };
  
var width = 500,
 height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force()
 .size([width, height])
 .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    })
 .linkDistance(d => d.distance)
 .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#orb")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .attr("class", "mainsvg");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
 node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
 path = svg.selectAll(".path");

force.nodes(data.nodes)
 .links(data.links)
 .start();
var edges = link.data(data.links)
 .enter()
 .append("line")
 .attr("class", "link")
 .style("stroke", "grey")
 .style("pointer-events", "none");
node = node.data(data.nodes)
 .enter()
 .append("g");
node.append("circle")
 .attr("class", "circle")
 .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
 .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} })
 .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} });
var linkwrap = node.append("a")
 .attr("href", "3");
linkwrap.append("image")
 .attr("class", "srcico")
 .attr("height", "16px")
 .attr("width", "16px")
 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.icon; });
linkwrap.append("text")
 .attr("fill", "white")
 .attr("stroke", "none")
 .attr("x", "232")
 .attr("y", "255")
    .text(function(d) { return d.ticker; });

function tick() {
 var link = svg.selectAll("line");
 var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath");
 var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel");
 link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
 svg.selectAll(".srcico")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x-5; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y-8; });
 svg.selectAll(".notecap")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
var inter = setInterval(function() { 
                updateData();
        setTimeout(function(){
         force.linkDistance(20);
         force.start().alpha(0.01);
        },2000);
        }, 5000); 

function updateData() {
var data = {

    nodes: [
   {"x": 250, "y": 250, "color": "grey", "name":"TEST", "r":"28", "fixed":true},
    {"x": 120, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": -12.2, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 140, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": -0.08, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": -0.055, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 300, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": 0.45, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 40, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.27, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 70, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.28, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 100, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.3, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 130, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.72, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 380, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.66, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 160, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.317, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.37, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 270, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.49, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 340, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.62, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 100, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.31, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 140, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.457, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 180, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.472, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.66, "icon": ""},   
    {"x": 320, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.68, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 410, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.8, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 260, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.86, "icon": ""}
    ],
   links: [
    {"source":  0, "target": 1, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 2, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 3, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 4, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 5, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 6, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 7, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 8, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 9, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 10, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 11, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 12, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 13, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 14, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 15, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 16, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 17, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 18, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 19, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 20, "distance": 180, "label": ""}
  ]
    };

d3.selectAll(".mainsvg > *").remove();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
 node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
 path = svg.selectAll(".path");
 
 force.linkDistance(d=>d.distance);


 force.nodes(data.nodes)
  .links(data.links)
  .start();
 var edges = link.data(data.links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke", "grey")
  .style("pointer-events", "none");
 node = node.data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
 node.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} })
  .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} });
 var linkwrap = node.append("a")
  .attr("href", "3");
 linkwrap.append("image")
 .attr("class", "srcico")
 .attr("height", "16px")
 .attr("width", "16px")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.icon; });
  linkwrap.append("text")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("x", "232")
  .attr("y", "255")
    .text(function(d) { return d.ticker; });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="orb">
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly it! I'd swap out update though, since they should pulse before they update, but that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you

Comment: Hey Gerardo, may have ran into a problem with this one, since I'm using a function to do the initial build, some of the vars are missing, but when I add them, it just breaks down. Would it be too much if I post the entire thing for you to check?

Comment: This isn't me being lazy by the way, it's just I'm missing some `d3` vars that are declared inside a scope, and when I re-declare them, I do it wrong. Figured it'd be a second for you

Comment: Hey Sam, post it as another question... I'm about to get offline for some time. If you post it here, I'm the only one going to have a look at it, but if you post it as an individual question, the whole community is going to see it!

Comment: Yeah I'll do that I just figured it'll be easier like this considering you're familiar with the majority of the code. But yeah, I'll post a new one. Thanks again man!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I can help you. But the problem is: *when*? Post it as another question, and tomorrow morning (when I'll be online again), if no one has answered it already, I'll try.

Comment: It's perfectly fine don't worry about it! It's a common logic js/jq problem, I'm sure someone will have an idea how to fix it :)

Comment: So you don't have to search, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477135/d3-js-animation-in-conjuction-with-jquery-update please don't rush it, if and when you can, feel free to glance it over :)