# D3.js animation in conjuction with jQuery update

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Alrighty, so I'm using the majority of the code listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475286/d3-js-animating-update). Keeping the animation in mind, what I want to do is use jQuery to load data dynamically. However, since I have it wrapped in a function, like so:

```
function dataGrab(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'somelink.php?param=someparam',
            dataType: 'text',
            async: true,
            data: "", 
            success: function (data) {


                buildGraph(data);

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error");
            }

})
};
```

And the build graph hosts carbon copy of the code from the question, like this:

```
function buildGraph(pureData)
{

var temp = pureData;
var data = JSON.parse(temp);
var width = 500,
    height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    })
    .linkDistance(d => d.distance)
    .on("tick", tick);
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#orb")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "mainsvg");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    path = svg.selectAll(".path");
force.nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(data.links)
    .start();
var edges = link.data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "grey")
    .style("pointer-events", "none");
node = node.data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "#24b8e3";} })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "#24b8e3";} });
var linkwrap = node.append("a")
    .attr("href", "3");
linkwrap.append("image")
    .attr("class", "srcico")
    .attr("height", "16px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { if(d.icon.length > 25) { return d.icon; } });


function tick() {
    var link = svg.selectAll("line");
    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath");
    var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel");


    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    svg.selectAll(".circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    svg.selectAll(".srcico")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x-5; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y-8; });
    svg.selectAll(".notecap")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
}


dataGrab();
var inter = setInterval(function() {

    dataGrab();
    setTimeout(function() {
        force.linkDistance(20);
        force.start().alpha(0.01);
    }, 2000);

}, 5000);
```

I'm having various problems, considering that all my vars such as `svg` and `force` are delcared inside the `dataGrab()` scope. I've tried declaring them outside, I've tried re-declaring them in the same fashion, inside `setInterval`, but whatever I do, something insane happens, or I get no error, but it doesn't work. I've also tried building 1 root node (grey one from the example in the linked question) and updating only the others, via the written ajax, but it doesn't work. So what I'd like to do is the same thing that's the answer to the question, only using `jQuery`. This code will run fine if ran once, however, the update part is where I run into a problem. Thanks!

PS, for clarification, or to avoid having to click links, this is the result needed, only with `jQuery`

```js
var data = {

    nodes: [
   {"x": 250, "y": 250, "color": "green", "name":"TEST", "r":"28", "fixed":true},
    {"x": 120, "y": 150, "name":"forums.macrumors", "score": -12.2, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 140, "y": 150, "name":"delhidailynews", "score": -0.08, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 150, "name":"4-traders", "score": -0.055, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 300, "y": 150, "name":"phonearena", "score": 0.45, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 40, "y": 200, "name":"inga3.wordpress", "score": -0.27, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 70, "y": 200, "name":"kahinaweb.wordpress", "score": -0.28, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 100, "y": 200, "name":"bilqueessite.wordpress", "score": -0.3, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 130, "y": 200, "name":"beforeitsnews", "score": -0.72, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 380, "y": 200, "name":"yahoo", "score": -0.66, "icon": ""}    
    ],
   links: [
    {"source":  0, "target": 1, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 2, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 3, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 4, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 5, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 6, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 7, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 8, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 9, "distance": 180, "label": ""}
   

    
  ]
    };
  
var width = 500,
 height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force()
 .size([width, height])
 .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    })
 .linkDistance(d => d.distance)
 .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#orb")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .attr("class", "mainsvg");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
 node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
 path = svg.selectAll(".path");

force.nodes(data.nodes)
 .links(data.links)
 .start();
var edges = link.data(data.links)
 .enter()
 .append("line")
 .attr("class", "link")
 .style("stroke", "grey")
 .style("pointer-events", "none");
node = node.data(data.nodes)
 .enter()
 .append("g");
node.append("circle")
 .attr("class", "circle")
 .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
 .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} })
 .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} });
var linkwrap = node.append("a")
 .attr("href", "3");
linkwrap.append("image")
 .attr("class", "srcico")
 .attr("height", "16px")
 .attr("width", "16px")
 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.icon; });
linkwrap.append("text")
 .attr("fill", "white")
 .attr("stroke", "none")
 .attr("x", "232")
 .attr("y", "255")
    .text(function(d) { return d.ticker; });

function tick() {
 var link = svg.selectAll("line");
 var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath");
 var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel");
 link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
 svg.selectAll(".srcico")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x-5; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y-8; });
 svg.selectAll(".notecap")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
var inter = setInterval(function() { 
                updateData();
        setTimeout(function(){
         force.linkDistance(20);
         force.start().alpha(0.01);
        },2000);
        }, 5000); 

function updateData() {
var data = {

    nodes: [
   {"x": 250, "y": 250, "color": "grey", "name":"TEST", "r":"28", "fixed":true},
    {"x": 120, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": -12.2, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 140, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": -0.08, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": -0.055, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 300, "y": 210, "name":"", "score": 0.45, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 40, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.27, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 70, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.28, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 100, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.3, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 130, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.72, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 380, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.66, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 160, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.317, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.37, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 270, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.49, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 340, "y": 200, "name":"", "score": -0.62, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 100, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.31, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 140, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.457, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 180, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.472, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 280, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.66, "icon": ""},   
    {"x": 320, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.68, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 410, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.8, "icon": ""},
    {"x": 260, "y": 300, "name":"", "score": -0.86, "icon": ""}
    ],
   links: [
    {"source":  0, "target": 1, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 2, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 3, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 4, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 5, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 6, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 7, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 8, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 9, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 10, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 11, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 12, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 13, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 14, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 15, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 16, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 17, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 18, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 19, "distance": 180, "label": ""},
    {"source":  0, "target": 20, "distance": 180, "label": ""}
  ]
    };

d3.selectAll(".mainsvg > *").remove();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
 node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
 path = svg.selectAll(".path");
 
 force.linkDistance(d=>d.distance);


 force.nodes(data.nodes)
  .links(data.links)
  .start();
 var edges = link.data(data.links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke", "grey")
  .style("pointer-events", "none");
 node = node.data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
 node.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} })
  .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "orange";} });
 var linkwrap = node.append("a")
  .attr("href", "3");
 linkwrap.append("image")
 .attr("class", "srcico")
 .attr("height", "16px")
 .attr("width", "16px")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.icon; });
  linkwrap.append("text")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("x", "232")
  .attr("y", "255")
    .text(function(d) { return d.ticker; });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="orb">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I managed to solve it. I've moved build graph outside the function, as to only define the variables properly. So imagine the exact same code outside the function.
After that, use the exact same code to make an update function say `update(pureData){` and make it look something like this (full draw/update code):

```
var data = { // insert root node here or leave empty doesn't matter, we're keeping this outside the functions only to set d3 vars proper }
var width = 500,
    height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    })
    .linkDistance(d => d.distance)
    .on("tick", tick);
var svg = d3.select("#holderIdHere")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "mainsvg");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    path = svg.selectAll(".path");
force.nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(data.links)
    .start();
var edges = link.data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "grey")
    .style("pointer-events", "none");
node = node.data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "#24b8e3";} })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "#24b8e3";} });
var linkwrap = node.append("a")
    .attr("href", "3");
linkwrap.append("image")
    .attr("class", "srcico")
    .attr("height", "16px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { if(d.icon.length > 25) { return d.icon; } });


function tick() {
    var link = svg.selectAll("line");
    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath");
    var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel");


    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    svg.selectAll(".circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    svg.selectAll(".srcico")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x-5; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y-8; });
    svg.selectAll(".notecap")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function updateMe(newData)
{
  var data = newData;
d3.selectAll("#holderIdHere").remove();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    path = svg.selectAll(".path");
force.nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(data.links)
    .start();
var edges = link.data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "grey")
    .style("pointer-events", "none");
node = node.data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { if(d.r){ return d.r; } else { return "18";} })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "#24b8e3";} })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.color) { return d.color; } else { return "#24b8e3";} });
var linkwrap = node.append("a")
    .attr("href", "3");
linkwrap.append("image")
    .attr("class", "srcico")
    .attr("height", "16px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { if(d.icon.length > 25) { return d.icon; } });


function tick() {
    var link = svg.selectAll("line");
    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath");
    var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel");


    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    svg.selectAll(".circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    svg.selectAll(".srcico")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x-5; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y-8; });
    svg.selectAll(".notecap")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
}
```

After this, all you have to do is throw `AJAX` and fetch your data, like so:

```
function graphUp(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'somelink',
        dataType: 'text',
        async: true,
        data: "", 
        success: function (data) {
           var freshdata = data;
           var newData= jQuery.parseJSON(freshdata);

                updateData(newData);

       },
        error: function (result) {
        }
}
)};
```

And set the update animation to look nice like this:

```
var inter = setInterval(function() {
    graphUp();
    setTimeout(function() {
        force.linkDistance(20);
        force.start().alpha(0.01);
    }, 2000);
}, 5000);
```

Many thanks to [Gerardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768908/gerardo-furtado) and his answer for animation fix found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476340/2609029)

Now naturally, I'm certain this isn't the most elegant solution, since I'm not the most elegant developer, but it works. The method will pretty much re-render the full data all the time, so if someone would like to pitch in and add an update method to this, feel free